# storing a Book using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi and thank you for your attention

I'm working on a database system project and i must implement a digital library using SQL Server.

I dont know how can i store a book with 1000 pages (page by page and with serching ability) in SQL Server

I was thinking about creating a table with 1000 columns with ntext type,but i think it isn't really a wise way.

could anyone help me with a suitable method for this problem.

I also going to store multipage image books and voice books

thank you.

Comment: Please have a look on these links - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx), [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx)

Comment: Don't use `NTEXT` - it's been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead - it can store up to 2 GB of data - that's about 1 billion characters, or more than 200 times the size of Tolstoj's `War and Peace` ...

Answer (score 2):

1000 columns? No rather a 1000 rows in a table such as:

```
Table BookPage:
   BookId int
   PageId int
   PageText ntext
```

You could then have another table for the book:

```
Table Book:
   BookId int
   Title nvarchar
   Author nvarchar
```

Comment: as stated previously, the text data type is marked for removal in future version of sql server.  insteade please use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)